# ruby-on-rails app using webbrick server slow on some machines

Tags: web-server, ruby-on-rails

I have a fairly simple ruby-on-rails app developed on mac, that was put into production on a debian web server.   The web app uses the default webbrick server provided to run the app.

The app runs quick on my machine and many others around my area.  However, it runs slow on a couple of machines.  Accordingly to the logs provided by webbrick, the pages are rendered in miliseconds but on the machines that are slow, it takes 15 - 20 seconds for the machine to get the message to actually render the page.

I've researched the available solutions on what could be causing this, but none have returned a viable solution in my case.

Right now, I'm considering switching my server over to Apache to run my app, but I'm not sure if the same problem will persist because I don't really know what the problem is!  Does anyone have any suggestions?

---

Some info about the machines I've tested this on:

3 Mac Pro's (Mac OSX) - All run the app quickly.  The Computers are connected inside our users network

1 Mac Air (Mac OSX) - Runs quickly. Connected inside our network

1 Macbook Pro (Mac OSX) - Runs fairly slow but not slowest.  Not connected inside our network

1 Dell Laptop (Ubuntu) - Same performance as the Macbook Pro

1 Dell Workstation(Windows) - Slowest of them all.  Large lagtime on pages.  Connected inside our network.  This is the machine we need it to be quick on.

1 Dell Desktop (Windows) - Another Slow machine.  Conncected inside our network

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't the problem that on your devs machines the server is accepting just one request and in production is accepting multiple concurrent requests?

Anyway, Webrick isn't a good server for production environments. I prefer Unicorn or Puma, but Passenger is a good option also and simpler to configure.

Comment: turns out it was Webrick that was the problem.  Switched over to a new server and now the app is running smoothly on all machines.

Answer (score 1):

Since your app works on several workstations, chances are that the slowness is due to a problem on the problem workstations.

I will assume that your app runs consistently on each machine - that is that on the machines where it runs quickly, it always runs quickly.

What are the differences in computer hardware, operating system, software, and network between the computers where it works and the computers where the app doesn't work? If the computers where the app doesn't work are all on a different subnet, there might be a routing problem or high network congestion on that subnet. If they are running an older operating system or an older browser, they might not be fully compatible with the code in your app. If they are running additional background tasks or have a small amount of RAM or free disk space, address those issues and try again.

There are so many variables in web design that can impact performance, but in your case I think the indications are that it is a client issue and not a server issue. Of course, any developer knows that code can always be better optimized. Even if this is a client issue, more optimal code in your app might improve performance on those clients. Head over to SO for help with that.

If your app does not run consistently on each machine - if it runs slowly on a machine that it previously ran quickly on - then there might be a server issue to address. In that case, check your CPU, RAM, and network usage and correlate that with your slow app performance. Your web server might be processing the app quickly, but then hit a bottleneck on delivery. You can always try it on Apache and see if that solves your problem (Apache is free and relatively easy to set up, so it's not hard to use it just as a test).

Comment: I've added some information on the different machines I'm running this app on.  Your insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Those two Dell workstations - can you specify hardware configurations and browsers that you're using? My first guess is that they're older machines. My second guess is that you're using an out of date or incompatible browser. It's interesting that both of the slow machines are Windows machines. What version of Windows are they running? My third guess is that your application is a client-side monster.

Comment: The Desktop is the oldest of them all.  The Workstation we have is fairly new, high RAM, high processing power.  Both are running windows 7 with the latest version of chrome.

Comment: Before doing anything else, you should try using a different browser. I'm not suggesting that Chrome is a bad browser, but comparing the performance across multiple platforms is part of troubleshooting. If it renders the same on that machine using IE, Firefox, and Opera, then we know it's not the browser.